# Why is this code not awaiting import of modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to dynamically import modules when the `nodejs` server is in `development` environment. I have created an immediately-invoked `async` function for this which theoretically should work, but it simply doesn't. The rest of the code following the import of modules runs without awaiting for the import to finish.

**server.js**

```
    import express from 'express'; // standard import
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // IIFE to dynamically import modules required in dev
     (
      async () => {
            
         try {
         console.log(`About to import`)
         //simple destructuring used to get the default export out of the modules
         const {default: webpack} = await import('webpack');
         const {default: webpackDevMiddleware} = await import('webpack-dev-middleware');
         console.log(`FIRST: typeof webpack ${typeof Webpack} | typeof webpackdevmiddleware ${typeof WebpackDevMiddleware}`)
          } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)
          }
       })();
     }
    
    const server = express();
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // Need to use imported modules here but this code does not wait for the webpack imports above to finish
    console.log(`SECOND: I must run after FIRST`)
    }
    
    ....
    server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port 8080`);
});
```

When I run the `server.js` code I get the following output in this order:

> About to import
>
> SECOND: I must run after FIRST
>
> Server is listening on port 8080
>
> FIRST: typeof webpack function | typeof webpackdevmiddleware function

The correct order needs to be:

> About to import
>
> FIRST: typeof webpack function | typeof webpackdevmiddleware function
>
> SECOND: I must run after FIRST
>
> Server is listening on port 8080

I cannot understand where/why it is going wrong?

Comment: Remove the `async` IIFE and directly execute the code inside; just use top-level `await`.

Comment: @Unmitigated what do you mean? can you provide example? If I just write `await import('webpack')` without an asyc

Comment: I mean directly write `const {default: webpack} = await import('webpack');` inside the if statement without the async IIFE.

Comment: Essentially, use the `.mjs` extension, then Node will allow direct `await` at the top level without an async IIFE.

Comment: @Unmitigated I get an error in node saying "`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`"

Comment: Change the file extension to `.mjs`.

Comment: Move your entire code to the iife and it will work fine or use `then`

Comment: @Konrad Why wont the async IIFE work and resolve before the rest of the code in the file runs?

Comment: @volumeone Because the rest of your code is outside the async IIFE and is running before the async IIFE finishes. Calling async functions does not stop the execution of the rest of the program unless you use `await`. (Alternatively, you can also wait for promises by using `.then`.)

Comment: In any case, does using `.mjs` with top level `await` not work for you?

Comment: You don't apparently understand how an `async` function works.  At the point it hits the first `await` inside the `async` function, that `async` function immediately pauses further execution of the function and then immediately returns a promise.  The calling code of that `async` function receives the promise as the return value and then continues merrily executing the code that follows UNLESS it also `awaits` the returned promise which means it has to be `async` or top level.

Comment: @Unmitigated I am having to rewrite the entire server.js file to use `.mjs` because other code in the file imports json files etc using `require`. Getting some problems so will confirm once I work through it all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have already suggested in the comments, this pattern of executing something is called IIFE:

```
(async () => { /* ... */ })();
```

Since it is asnychronous it will not "wait" until finished but execute parallel to the code following.

If you want something to happen in sequential order, you have to include that part inside the `async` environment as well or name the file `something.mjs` so you can use `await` in the top level.